# Python: Using the list length to increment the index of the enumerated dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, enumeration

I am looping and enumerating a dictionary as following:

```
for column, key, in enumerate(guid_material_dictionary.iteritems()):
            print column, key, len(key[1])
```

It gives the following output:

```
0 ('0GVHv3rDXBewxnxizHODe9', ['Steen', 'Isolatie', 'Spouw']) 3
1 ('2kj3p602r8MgLr9ocS99Pp', ['Beton C']) 1
2 ('3_gGbJ1L17UP8z1VVIOPak', ['Beton', 'Pleister', 'Baksteen', 'Folie']) 4
3 ('3mROnO4_7VbAI2oRYB55vS', ['Koper']) 1
4 ('1HX$_kbR1AKxF1CmKGciQa', ['Steen - kalkzandsteen']) 1
5 ('0xtMj9XwvBjvPzzyvlFeQ0', ['Isolatie - Steenwol zacht']) 1
```

The list lengths vary a lot in the output.
What I am trying to do is to use the list length to increment the column count.
So that the column count is defined by the lengths of the list. This output is an example of what I intent to do.

```
0 ('0GVHv3rDXBewxnxizHODe9', ['Steen', 'Isolatie', 'Spouw']) 3
3 ('2kj3p602r8MgLr9ocS99Pp', ['Beton C']) 1
4 ('3_gGbJ1L17UP8z1VVIOPak', ['Beton', 'Pleister', 'Baksteen', 'Folie']) 4
8 ('3mROnO4_7VbAI2oRYB55vS', ['Koper']) 1
9 ('1HX$_kbR1AKxF1CmKGciQa', ['Steen - kalkzandsteen']) 1
10 ('0xtMj9XwvBjvPzzyvlFeQ0', ['Isolatie - Steenwol zacht']) 1
```

I hope the question is clear. What I tried is to add the colum integers with the list length but it does not work because the column needs to be defined by the list lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the `enumerate` part and use a variable:

```
column = 0
for key in guid_material_dictionary.iteritems():
    print column, key, len(key[1])
    column += len(key[1])
```

Note that you increase the `column` variable after using it.

---

*Note* that the order of dictionary keys is **arbitrary**, so you can't really match the `column` variable with the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `enumerate` for that. But it is easy enough to write your own generator:

```
def my_enumerate(iterable):
    total = 0
    for key, value in iterable:
        yield total, (key, value)
        total += len(value)
```

So you can use it like this:

```
for column, key in my_enumerate(guid_material_dictionary.iteritems()):
    print column, key, len(key[1])
```